# Changing the Color of QLineEdit's Placeholder Text

Tags: c++, css, qt

I am writing an application in Qt 4.8 and taking advantage of styling through CSS. When styling QLineEdit there are properties such as `selection-background-color`, is there a property that will allow me to change the color of placeholder text?

If not, are there any other methods of changing it?

Comment: hm, I dont know of any specific, but I would simply color the text per default as you wish and connect the `QLineEdit::textChanged( const QString& ) ` signal to a function checking if the text is still the placeholder and if not -> color otherwise/different stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

The color of the placeholder is the color of the text with alpha set to 50%.
At least in 4.7 this was hardcoded and could thus not be changed with style.

As the decision is implemented in QLineEdit::paintEvent you could override paintEvent in a derived class and change the color to whatever suits you fine.

But why would you want a different color? If you change it to red or something like that, you might irritate a user who cannot distinguish a placeholder from "real" text anymore.

Comment: I am not trying to change it to red, however since my application supports multiple styles, the placeholder text does not look ideal under certain configurations. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the text is just 50% alpha of the line edit's text so if you set the color of the line edit's text in the CSS, the placeholder text should change as well

Comment: here if sources of 4.7 painting placeholder: if (d->control->text().isEmpty()) {
        if (!hasFocus() && !d->placeholderText.isEmpty()) {
            QColor col = pal.text().color();
            col.setAlpha(128);
            QPen oldpen = p.pen();
            p.setPen(col);
            lineRect.adjust(minLB, 0, 0, 0);
            QString elidedText = fm.elidedText(d->placeholderText, Qt::ElideRight, lineRect.width());
            p.drawText(lineRect, va, elidedText);
            p.setPen(oldpen);
            return;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can connect a palette change to the signal textChanged(): You change the text color when the line edit is empty.